# Local Notifications are working in the simulator, but doesn't work when i test it on my actual device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, local

I have a timer that function that calls a local notification timer ever set amount of seconds and its supposed to run until stopped by a button.

Everything is in my viewcontroller.m file.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)Timer{
//num is a slider value
num1 = num*60.0;
self.ShowerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:num1
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(notification)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];


}
```

My Notification that should go off.

```
-(void)notification{

//NSDate *alarmTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:num];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

UILocalNotification *notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

// get current date/time
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
//NSLog(@"User's current time in their preference format:%@",currentTime);

notifyAlarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
notifyAlarm.soundName = @"";
notifyAlarm.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Notified at %@",currentTime];
[app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
}
```

Comment: Did you write the receiving code for the local notification?

Comment: please provide your all code which you do for local notification

Comment: Did you make sure, that push notifications where - at no point - disabled? Also for Local Push you do now (iOS8 and later) need the acceptance from the user. Please have a look at: Settings -> Notifications on your device

Comment: @SahebRoy what is the recieving code?

Comment: @Lepidopteron Yes I have it in the launchedwithoptions in appdelegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My first advise** would be set your timer on main loop.

Without property:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // Enclose your timer code here
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:num1 target:self selector:@selector(notification) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
});
```

If you want to keep your property:

```
__weak MyViewController *aBlockSelf = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // Enclose your timer code here
   aBlockSelf.showTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:num1 target:self selector:@selector(notification) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
});
```

**Second,** you do not need to keep reference of your timer like in this --> `self.ShowerTimer`. This is because Run Loop keeps a strong reference to a repeating timer.

**Third,** your variable naming convention is off. `ShowerTimer` should be named as `showerTimer`. Although this is nothing to do with your problem.

**Finally**, your code looks fine and if notification is working on Simulator, check **Do Not Disturb** setting on your device. It should be off for local notification to show up.

Comment: I'll try it what exactly does dispatch_async do? Just makes it priority que?

Comment: how will i call my timer function from the dispatch?

Comment: in my start button action I'm calling [self Timer]; to start the timer, how do i pull it from dispatch?

Comment: still works in the simulator but not when i transfer it to my phone

Comment: Did you check Do Not Disturb setting on device?

Comment: yes its clear, another thing i sometimes get the notification but no banner when i press the stop action button